# What does <%anything%> do?

Tags: ruby, erb

In Rails tutorials and vids, it seems totally different from regular ruby. For example, I see `<%render%>` or `<%end%>`. When am I supposed to use `<%%>` and what is it for?

Comment: Use that when you are using any ruby or rails code in your erb template

Answer (score 3):

`<% code %>` is used in `erb`, which stands for "Embedded Ruby".  It's typically used in HTML generating templates.  It's brother is `<%= code %>` which outputs the return value of the expression inside it.

```
<h1>Hello, <%= @user.name %>!</h1>
# potentially renders: <h1>Hello, Bob</h1>
# potentially renders: <h1>Hello, Sue</h1>
```

The non-outputting `<% code %>` version of this tag is useful for executing code, but not writing anything to the template.  This is useful for conditionals (as well as other things).

```
<h1>
  Hello
  <% if @user.sex == 'male' %>
    Mister
  <% else %>
    Miss
  <% end %>
  <%= @user.name %>!
</h1>

# potentially renders: <h1>Hello Mister Bob!</h1>
# potentially renders: <h1>Hello Miss Sue!</h1>
```

In pure ruby, this would be a syntax error.  But within an `erb` template, these tags allow you to control how the template renders by executing ruby to control the template flow, and by writing out the result of ruby expressions.

Rails uses `erb` by default for it's views, which are mostly html generating templates.  So you see this a lot in Rails examples.  Just keep in mind that `erb` is just one option for your templates in Rails.  [There is a great many options, which may use different syntax entirely.](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/template_engines)

Answer (score 0):

That is used in HTML code to display ruby code inside the tags.

```
<%= render 'folder/partial_form' %>
```

That will render a form partial.

I suggest you have a nice long read through the links below:

http://www.guides.rubyonrails.org

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0):

The `<%= %>` and `<% %>` syntax is used to write ruby in a .erb file.  Think of ERB as an html file that always allows ruby code to be run.  The `<% %>` syntax runs the ruby but does nothing by default while the `<%= %>` syntax(notice the =) outputs the result of the ruby code to the screen.